# Failed to parse List of elements with attributes

Tags: java, xml, jackson, fasterxml

I have object Links that has a member of List while Link has only attributes but parsing of the list has something wrong - it is created empty.
In the test below `links.getLinks()` returns empty list. Any ideas?
XML example:

```
<links>
<link x="1" y="2" />
<link x="3" y="4" />
</links>
```

The Java

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName="links")
public class Links extends BaseAmebaElement {

@JacksonXmlProperty(localName="link")
//@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName="link")
private Collection<Link> links;

public Collection<Link> getLinks() {
    return links;
}

public void setLinks(Collection<Link> links) {
    this.links = links;
}
}
```

...

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName="link")
public class Link {

@JacksonXmlProperty(localName="x", isAttribute=true)
private String href;

@JacksonXmlProperty(localName="y", isAttribute=true)
private String rel;
```

...

```
    XmlMapper  xmlMapper = new XmlMapper ();
    try {
        Links links = xmlMapper.readValue(input, Links.class);
        assertNotNull(links);
        assertNotNull(links.getLinks());
        assertEquals(2, links.getLinks().size());
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        fail(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

I could get the result after some changes. However, it could get first row out (it is null). And I don't know why.

```
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping=false)
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName="link")
private Collection<Link> links;
```

Updated:
This should be a bug in version 2.1.4. I just tried [master](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml), this works fine.

Comment: Make sure you have the latest version (2.1.4) in use. Your code and annotations look correct to me.

Comment: @StaxMan Yes, I am using 2.1.4 (com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.1.4).

Comment: I tried the same thing... in different versions of the tries I also seen this problem - the first element is always null in the list. If I have 5 elements - the first is null and the other 4 are inside. I also checked if there is problem with the element - but NO, even same content in all elements gives the first one to be null :( Since this was for practice and POC only - my final and fast way to resolve it was to use XStream. However, the down side of using XStream is the fact that you MUST parse all data, it is super strict and sensitive to changes in the model.

Comment: It sounds like 2.2.0-SNAPSHOT will work, and 2.2.0 should be released very soon (within 2 weeks). Sorry to hear 2.1.4 has these issues. One final thing: some issues are related to use of SJSXP Stax parser (from JDK), and Woodstox (http://woodstox.codehaus.org) works better. So it's worth using instead.

Comment: I've tried essentially exactly this use case with 2.2.0, and I'm still seeing this bug, with both the standard JDK Stax parser and with the Woodstox parser.

Comment: Oops. I take that back. When I removed the `@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping=false)` annotation everything worked fine.